# Using jQuery promise to wait for transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-deferred

I have a layout with 2 divs- `#lhs` and `#rhs` and a function that would change their width. Both sides have transitions on, and I want to make something happen when they finish to set their width (in this example - an alert)

problem is that the alert fires as soon as they start to change width and not after

```
function setLHSWidth(percent){

    $("#lhs").css("width", percent + "%")
    $("#rhs").css("width", 100 - percent + "%");

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").on("click", function(){
     var percent = Math.random() * 100;

        setLHSWidth(percent);

        $("#lhs").promise().done(function(){
           alert('done!'); 
        });
    });
});

<div class="wrap">
    <div id="lhs">
    </div>

    <div id="rhs">
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is the fiddle to play with http://jsfiddle.net/xv43Lasy/1/ (updated with longer transition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery promises only work on animations performed by jQuery, and not on CSS transitions.

You can either:

1. use jQuery itself to perform the animations (most portable), or
2. catch the `transitionend` event - demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/v7vn94ea/

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend for more information on the latter.

Comment: oh, thanks. Is that for all browsers or there are browser specific events? 'webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd transitionend' ?

Comment: added link to MDN site which has browser specific details.  Alternatively just use jQuery to perform the animations, and then uses promises.